# Is it acceptable to have a privileged account with a shard password on multiple systems?

Tags: privileges

I have a scanning tool, Nexpose, that requires a user account to have sudo privileges.  Our Linux systems at this point do not use Kerberos, LDAP, or anything centralized. Most of these systems run RHEL 5 or Solaris 10.

Is it considered acceptable to do the following:

- Create a privileged account on each system with a shared password
- Disable the account
- Require a sysadmin to enable the account on each relevant system prior to initiating scan
- Require a sysadmin to disable the account after scanning

Comment: If this is a service account why not modify your sudo config, so that it can use sudo without a password for the specific tools it needs to run?  How does Nexpose remotely access the systems?  SSH,  if so then setup key-based authentication for that.  Anyway, in short, you should need a shared **password** for this.  You should be able to setup password-less authentication for this service.

Comment: This question might belong on Security.SE.